# Strange behavior by setting NULL in array

Tags: c, char, printf, sizeof

I've a strange behavior while i'm trying to set a NULL value at the end of array of string (array of char) in c. I need to pass parameters to a process with execv, and i've all parameters with int type, so i'm trying to get an array of strings with all parameters casted in char array. I made a function that returns this array of strings, but when I set the last value of array to NULL (to have a terminating value in parameters) I lost the value stored in second position. If I remove the NULL value, no issue happens. This is the code, hope someone can help me

```c
char **getParams(int offset, short isNode, int first) {

    printf("Get params\n");

    int args = 8;
    int totalSize = 0;
    int tmp[args];

    tmp[0] = sizeof(char) * 5; // user / node
    tmp[1] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x);
    tmp[2] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x2);
    tmp[3] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x3);
    tmp[4] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x4);
    tmp[5] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x5);
    tmp[6] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x6);
    tmp[7] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x7);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < args; i++) totalSize += tmp[i];

    char **_pars = malloc(totalSize + sizeof(NULL));
    
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < args; i++) _pars[i] = malloc(tmp[i]);
    
    _pars[0] = isNode == 1 ? "aaaa" : "bbbb" ;
    sprintf(_pars[1], "%d", x);
    sprintf(_pars[2], "%d", x2);
    sprintf(_pars[3], "%d", x3);
    sprintf(_pars[4], "%d", x4);
    sprintf(_pars[5], "%d", x5);
    sprintf(_pars[6], "%d", x6);
    sprintf(_pars[7], "%d", x7);
    printf("Value: %s", _pars[1]); /// Print without problem value
    _pars[8] = NULL;   //// ,--- Here happens the issue
    printf("Value: %s", _pars[1]); /// Doesnt print any value

    return _pars;
}
```

I also tried to put this after the for in which i malloc array position, but without result

```c
_pars[8] = malloc(sizeof(NULL));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your allocations are wrong.

First of all you want to create an array of `8` elements, so the first allocation should be

```
char **_pars = malloc(8 * sizeof *_pars);
```

Or if you want the array to be terminated by a null-pointer you need to allocate `9` elements (exchange the `8` for a `9` above).

Secondly the size returned by [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) does *not* include the null-terminator, so all your calls

```
_pars[i] = malloc(tmp[i]);
```

should be

```
_pars[i] = malloc(tmp[i] + 1);
```

to fit the null-terminator.

---

On another note, all your code could be simplified quite a lot if you put all the `x` values in an array:

```
int exes[8] = { x, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 };
```

Because then you could use loops for *all* repetitive code:

```
for (unsigned i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
{
    tmp[i] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", exes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer, is really helpful. But I don't understand what you mean when you say
`char **_pars = malloc(8 * sizeof *_pars);`, if i change the totalSize by assigning it correctly (by using + 1 to fit null terminator) is not the same thing? I don't understand how i can use sizeof (*_pars) if i've not defined a size for a single parameter

Comment: @EmmeDeveloper The size in `totalSize` is the size of the strings themselves (without the eight null-terminators), not the number of elements for the array `_pars`. Think of `_pars` as an *array of pointers* (equivalent to `char *_pars[8];`) and it would make more sense.

Comment: Oh ok got it thanks, i tried to allocate totalSize to use less memory, but i forget that each element of array must have the same size, so i cannot use totalSize but i need size of one element * number of element in the array. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`_pars` is assumed to be an array of pointers to char, which implies

```
_pars = malloc(args * sizeof(char*));
```

But you allocate the memory for the strings, the pointers should point to.